# Как выбрать победителя (победителей) из 3 участников?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Уточняю, вот пример массива массивов игроков. Тем, кто набрал больше очков, нужно добавить `+1` в `[won_tours]`. В данном примере это `Array[0]` и `Array[2]`.

Пробовал `asort()` и `arsort()`, но это не то, что нужно.
Пробовал с `if` - работает, но много ифов.

Интересны другие способы. 
Если я отсортирую по значению, как потом обратиться к нужному массиву?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bobby
            [last_tour_points] => 20
            [won_tours] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chuck
            [last_tour_points] => 10
            [won_tours] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Wendy
            [last_tour_points] => 20
            [won_tours] => 0
        )
)
```

В общем, я разобрался и цель достигнута:

1. Отсортировал с помощью `uasort`
2. Вытянул первый элемент с помощью `array_shift` для образца
3. Перебрал игроков циклом, сравнивая `'last_tour_points'` с образцом
4. При совпадении добавлял `+1` в `'won_tours'`

Спасибо всем, кто помог направить мысли в нужное направление.

Comment: День добрый. Опубликуйте лучше окончательное решение в виде ответа ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По просьбе [Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica) публикую свое окончательное решение в виде ответа. Если что судите строго, учу PHP только пару недель, любая критика интересна.

```
#######################################################
# найти победителей тура и добавить им +1 в won_tours #
#######################################################
# делаю копию массива, чтобы не было побочного эффекта для основоного массива
$whoo_win_tour = $players;

# отсортировать массив по значениям по возрастанию
uasort($whoo_win_tour, function($a, $b) {
return $b['last_tour_points'] - $a['last_tour_points'];
});

# так как после uasort индексы не упорядочены - извлекаю первый элемент с array_shift 
$whoo_win_tour = array_shift($whoo_win_tour);

# максимум очков за тур
$max_point_of_tour = $whoo_win_tour['last_tour_points'];

# в основном массиве победителям добавляем +1 в won_tours
for ($j = 0; $j < count($players); $j++) {
    if($players[$j]['last_tour_points'] == $max_point_of_tour) {
        $players[$j]['won_tours'] += 1;
        echo "<b>{$players[$j]['name']} победил!!!</b><br><br>"; 
    }
    # обнуляем last_tour_points для следующего тура
    $players[$j]['last_tour_points'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: вроде не хотели использовать сортировку. Чтобы получить первый элемент, массива, можно использовать `reset()`, а для цикла проще использовать `foreach($players as &$p){ ... }` и не таскать с собой индексы  `j`

Comment: максимум можно найти и вызовом `$max = max(array_column($players, 'last_tour_points'))`

Comment: Спасибо за ваши советы, мне на данный момент просто не хватает опыта, чтобы выбирать более оптимальные решения, я изучу ваши варианты и учту в будущем.

Answer (score 6):

Вы не показываете ваш код, поэтому попробуйте понять объяснение на пальцах.

If вообще не нужен: он и для массива из трёх участников неудобочитаемый, а если у вас N участников то трудностей ещё больше.

Метод расчёта победителей возвращает массив победителей, метод награждения в цикле проходит по массиву, добавляя победителям награждение.

Просто проходите по отсортированному по убыванию массиву награждая всех до тех пор пока у очередного победителя число баллов совпадает с числом баллов самого лучшего участника (нулевой элемент массива, можете запомнить в отдельную переменную), как только отличается -- выходите из цикла.

Comment: Спасибо, про массив тоже думал как вариант, я специально не показывал код, не хочу готовое решение, мне интересно было получить как раз именно такой ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуй, проще всего первым проходом по массиву найти максимальное количество баллов (был бы знакомый язык - набросал бы код, там все просто), второй проход - тем, у кого это количество баллов, добавлять по очку.

Примерно на псевдокоде:

```
max = a[1]
for i = 2 to N do if max < a[i] then max = a[i]

for i = 1 to N do if max = a[i] then a[i] = a[i] + 1
```

Главное - никакая сортировка массива при этом не нужна в принципе :)

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ тоже интересен, попробую и так и так.

Comment: Действительно, данный вариант проще предложенного мной: поиск максимума - менее трудоёмкая операция, чем сортировка. Рекомендую использовать его и сюда и галку поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно ввести ещё 1 параметр сравнения. Или общее время выполнения или время получения двадцатого очка.

Comment: Неочевидно, как это поможет решить проблему топикстартера, поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Поддерживаю А К, поясните пожалуйста.